# Test on Jenkins fails due to downloading that takes too long

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, automation, automated-tests

I'm using a testing infrastructure in a web UI,  in which I run tests on Jenkins.
One test fails in a certain step where we click on the download button and wait 300 seconds till a zip file is being downloaded.
Locally it downloads after a few seconds up to 90. But on Jenkins, it keeps failing and never downloading the package.

What can be the reason for this kind of issue?

Comment: Jenkins might not have filesystem write access to save the downloaded files.  here there can multiple reasons. 1. is the file processing is taking longer time in app side? 2. File Processed and ready to download but browser or Firewall can be blocking the file download. 3. Jenkins might not have write access to download and save the file to build directory.